# c#: should we have two different endpoint for clients i.e. UI and Service or create common endpoint for all cleints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have two layers from where all clients enter the application:

1. UI Layer: We have MVC, Webforms, JS code here.
   We call C# MVC controller in this project from JS. We use this for MSite/Desk clients. This returns back HTML to the clients.
2. Service Layer: This is Web API project. Android, IOS clients call this to get back JSON.

   Both have different URLs, 
   Its becoming tricky to have common validation for these two different entrypoints?

Should we make a common entrypoint i.e. UI calling service layer to get data? How can we do this? Or is there some other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your WEB API endpont as common endpont. All your client application should call endpoint only.

Your MVC application should also call the same web api which mobile apps are calling

Comment: but that would involve extra serialisation cost, how to avoid that

Comment: @sahil you didn't mention serialisation in your question, can you elaborate on how this is becoming a problem for you?

Comment: since service layer has WebAPIs, i need to call them through Http Client, they will return json. Further json will be converted to C# objects on UI.

Comment: you can also call web apis directly from UI using javascript, as you mentioned you are calling controller from javascript.

Comment: @MukulKeshari: what about the MVC, where we need to get data on page load OR partial view is returned from MVC?